# Keycode for "Delete" triggers browser's back button — jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button, keycode

I'm building a virtual keyboard that assigns images to keycodes, and appends them in spans after a keydown event. Problem comes with the DELETE functionality.

```
if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    $('span:last').remove(); 
}
```

Since everything happens outside of a textarea or input field, this triggers the browser's back button. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a <kbd>backspace</kbd>, not a <kbd>delete</kbd>, for starters.

Next, <kbd>backspace</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for "Back", so you MUST `return false;` in the event handler to prevent that default action taking place.

Comment: Yes, Backspace. I spaced and was referring to my Apple issued keyboard. Return false; solved me problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`return false` in whatever function you're handling that event. That should stop the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I wasn't too far away from success.

Comment: Hey, @pardon. Just in case you don’t know, once you have a definitive answer to your question, you should accept it by clicking the green check mark next to it. (Even if you solve your own problem, submit and answer and accept it.)